# multiple cascade delete path in many-many relationship (EF 4.1)

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, poco, ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.1

**THE TABLES:**

```
Shop
Product
Category
```

**THE RELATIONSHIPS:**

```
      (Shop) 1 <---> n (Categories)
      (Shop) 1 <---> n (Products)
(Categories) n <---> n (Products)
```

**THE CASCADE DELETES:**

```
      Shop  ---> Categories ... I defined this using fluent API
      Shop  ---> Products   ... I defined this using fluent API
Categories <---> Products   ... EF 4.1 automatically defines cascade for "Category_Product" join table
```

**THE PROBLEM:**
Above results in a "multiple" cascade deletion path exception.

**POTENTIAL FIXES:**

1. Remove the ManyToManyConvention, but that means I must manually perform deletes for every join table in the system, which is impractical.
2. I can remove the cascade delete from Shop->Category or Shop->Products. But then I'll probably have lots of orphaned records.

How are you folks dealing with this problem?

THANKS

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a problem of entity framework but the problem of SQL server. I don't think that exception actually means circular cascade delete. It more probably means multiple cascade delete paths because join table records can be deleted from both categories and products side because of cascading from shop. SQL server doesn't allow this because it requires some more complex (and slow) algorithms to correctly compute which records and when have to be deleted when cascading.

Simply you must break this and it will really mean that you will have to manually delete all related records (either categories or products) before you delete shop. This will require stored procedure (or direct SQL DELETE command) otherwise you will have to load all of them first and delete them one by one.

Edit:

As you pointed in the comment this can be also solved by adding BEFORE DELETE trigger which will delete related records if exists as replacement of one cascade path.

Comment: Yes I meant "multiple paths", my bad. I know about the SQL Server limitation, but it makes no sense, because when you delete Categories, it will delete Category_Product records in the JOIN TABLE, not actual Products records! But SqlServer still includes it in the cascade path... Weird huh? So triggers or sprocs are the only way???

Comment: I suppose a trigger that checks when the Shop is deleted, that all dependent records are deleted too, but then what's the point of the ORM? :-)

Comment: But if you delete shop it will delete both products and categories and once any of them is deleted it will also delete record from join table = delete can come from any side.

Comment: EF cascade deletes works in very close relation with database cascade deletes so it is not about ORM but about its implementation.

Comment: That is what I don't understand. Let's say I delete Shop, which deletes Categories. And I dont delete Products directly, but let the many-to-many cascade delete do it. That will work. BUT, the n:n cascade delete will remove all joined records from the join table, but it will not delete the actual records from the Products table. So I will have no Shop, no Categories, empty Category_Product table, but will still have all the Products records. Am I misunderstanding this?