# Entity Framework - Deleting Complex Object

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm have the following Entity Framwork objects:

Evaluation, Stage, Apartment

Evaluation contains many Stages and Stage contains many Apartments.

I'm trying to deleted a certain stage as follows:

```
var deletedStages =
  originalEvaluation.Stages.Where(s => s.State == StateTypes.Deleted);

deletedStages.ToList().ForEach(stage => 
{
  stage.Apartments.ToList().ForEach(
    apartment => stage.Apartments.Remove(apartment)
  );

  originalEvaluation.Stages.Remove(stage);
});

deletedStages.ToList().ForEach(stage =>
{
  stage.Apartments.ToList().ForEach(apartment =>
    shechtmanEntities.Apartments.DeleteObject(apartment)
  );

  shechtmanEntities.Stages.DeleteObject(stage);
});
}
}
try
{
  shechtmanEntities.SaveChanges();
}
```

But I'm keep getting an Exception : **"The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable"**.

I know it has to do with a null foreign-key, but I can't understand which? and Why?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you cannot Cascade Delete (SQL server can be funny about that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6065583/613004) asdutzu suggests, then:

If it's one-to-many relationship (sounds like it is), then you'll need to manually delete each child object and save-changes *before* deleting the parent. I.E. delete the apartment (or re-assign it to another Stage), then delete the stage, and so on.

Otherwise, if it's many-to-many, and the joining table is exposed through the entity model, delete the joins between the stages and apartments first, then delete the stage. If not, then `detach` the apartment from the stage and save changes before deleting the stage.

Answer (score 0):

Try just deleting the Evaluation or Stage and rely on a Cascade Delete to remove it's children entities (in your case Apartments) rather than removing them each individually.

Comment: I'm trying to delete a stage from within an Evaluation.
FYI - I've tryed just deleting the stage (without removing and deleting all it's apartments), it doesn't work (I get the same exception).

Comment: Then you should first delete the Apartments and commit changes and afterwards delete the Stages and commit changes. I would also surround this code with a TransactionScope to ensure that if something goes wrong you will not have the job half done.